# Decoupling Symfony bundles and making coupling loose or configurable

Tags: php, symfony

The case I'm trying to solve is:

I got bundle taking care of orders called 'OrderBundle' and wrote additional budle taking care of complaints - 'ComplaintsBundle' - the bundle is not fully standalone - the 
entity 'Complaint' is coupled with the entity 'Order' by the field 'order' inside 'Complaint' and - what I think is the 
real coupling problem - by the Doctrine annotation pointing to "Order".

What I'm thinking of and would like to achieve is to write a bundle 'Complaints' which can be standalone or have additional, optional fields which can be configured to couple with different entity. For example - the bundle 'Complaints' can serve as a complaints bundle for any 
entity which would eventually need complaints functionality.

The similiar situation I got with other bundles. Another example is 'User' entity from UserBundle which is related to 'Company' entity in CompanyBundle, 
but the thing again is that I want the UserBundle to be standalone bundle which can be easily installed among different projects which not necessary need the CompanyBundle but 
the User can be attached to another entity/entities. It goes futher because it is not only about doctrine annotations but views, created forms, validation,  and many other 
involved stuff.

What should be my approach to achieve that? Im quite new to symfony in fact and the idea of standalone reusable bundles is also quite new to me, before 
I didn't any bundles but was developing applications as a whole. Also I would like to develop other, not related to my job, open-source bundles to share with others, so 
I guess I need to apply to them this attitude of not being coupled to practically nothing else - how that can be achieved practically, can you share your experience, thoughts or point to explanatory articles?

Thank you very much for your guidelines and please take note it's a resonable question as there is a lack of know-how about decoupling bundles in Symfony community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your standalone bundles, you should declare your entities as abstract and set the doctrine annotation [@MappedSuperclass](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) on it.

Then, in your application, you will have to create your 'final' entities witch will be extend the mapped super class provided by your bundle.

Also, you will probably need to expose the FQCN of childs entities in your bundle configuration.

It can seem a little heavy, but unfortunatly Doctrine mapping is not overridable.

Here is some bundles implementing this solution :

- [Orbital/CmsBundle](https://github.com/Orbitale/CmsBundle)
- [FosUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)

To handle relations between your `MappedSuperclass` You have to use Interface in your relation annotation. Here is the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) about it.

Best regards

Comment: Thank you very much, I will write my own bundle now with your solution to test the idea. Best regards.

Comment: This might also help: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html